Azure DevOps REST API - Update pre-deployment artifacts
I'm trying to add a new branch to the target environment, specifically UAT, as part of the pre-condition artifacts. However, when I run the code, the release definition isn't displaying—it's just showing a blank page. Could someone help review and improve my code?
Here is my code snippet
$organization = "org"
$project = "contoso"
$token = "weird_token"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$definitionids = 510

$branchName = "release/24.3"
$targetEnv = "UAT"

foreach ($definitionid in $definitionids) 
{
    $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/definitions/${definitionId}?api-version=7.0"

    $Def = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token" } -Method GET -ContentType application/json
    
    $envId = 0
    $targetEnvId = 0

    foreach ($environment in $Def.environments)
    {
        $environmentName = $environment.name
        $envId++

        if ( $environmentName -eq $targetEnv )
        {
            Write-Host "INFO: Environment Name is $environmentName"
            
            $targetEnvId = $envId

            foreach ($condition in $environment.conditions)
            {
                if ($condition.conditionType -eq 'artifact')
                {
                    $newCondition = @{
                        sourceBranch = "$branchName"
                        tagFilter = $null
                        useBuildDefinitionBranch = $false
                        createReleaseOnBuildTagging = $false
                    }

                    Write-Host "INFO: Target Environment ID is $targetEnvId"

                    $artifactConditions = $Def.environments[$targetEnvId].conditions
                    $artifactConditions += $newCondition
                    $Def.environments[$targetEnvId].conditions = $artifactConditions
                    $updateDef_body = @($Def) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

                    $updateDef_body

                    Write-Host "INFO: adding release branch to release '$branchName' to release pipeline"
                    $updateDef_uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=7.0"
                    $updateDef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateDef_uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token" } -Method PUT -Body $updateDef_body -ContentType application/json
                    $updateDef
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Update
Here is the updated script to process the filter value for $newCondition
$organization = "org"
$project = "contoso"
$token = "weird_token"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$definitionids = 510 # 38 in my case

$branchName = "release/24.3"
$targetEnv = "UAT"

foreach ($definitionid in $definitionids) 
{
    $definitionid
    $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/definitions/${definitionId}?api-version=7.0"

    $Def = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token" } -Method GET -ContentType application/json
    $Def 
    $Def | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 # | Out-File "C:\Users\Alvin.AZ\Desktop\Def.json"

    foreach ($environment in $Def.environments)
    {
        $environmentName = $environment.name
        if ( $environmentName -eq $targetEnv )
        {

            Write-Host "INFO: Environment Name is $environmentName"
            Write-Host "INFO: artifactConditions are:"
            $artifactConditions = $environment.conditions
            $artifactConditions | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

            Write-Host "========================================New condition========================================"
            $filterVaule = @{
                sourceBranch = "$branchName"
                tags = @()
                useBuildDefinitionBranch = $false
                createReleaseOnBuildTagging = $false
            }
            $filterJsonVaule = $filterVaule | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress
            $filterJsonVaule
            $newCondition = @{
                conditionType = "artifact"
                name = "_PublishPipelineArtifacts-CI"
                value = "$filterJsonVaule"
            }
            $newCondition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

            Write-Host "========================================Environemnt UAT conditions========================================"
            $environment.conditions += $newCondition
            $environment.conditions | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

            Write-Host "========================================Update release pipeline definition ========================================"
            $updateDef_body = ConvertTo-Json($Def) -Depth 100 # | Out-File "C:\Users\Alvin.AZ\Desktop\newDef.json"
            $updateDef_body

            Write-Host "INFO: adding release branch to release '$branchName' to release pipeline"
            $updateDef_uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=7.0"
            $updateDef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateDef_uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token" } -Method PUT -Body $updateDef_body -ContentType application/json
            $updateDef

        }
    }
}



It appears you're checking if ($condition.conditionType -eq 'artifact') and adding a new artifact condition regardless of the existing conditions. This could potentially lead to unintended behavior in your release pipeline definition, when there is no pre-existing artifact conditions. While we don't know what your current release pipeline definition is like, below is a sample PowerShell script for your reference to add new artifact condition for UAT environment. Please pay attention to the new condition section and the proper indentation and formatting of $newCondition.
$organization = "org"
$project = "contoso"
$token = "weird_token"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$definitionids = 510 # 38 in my case

$branchName = "release/24.3"
$targetEnv = "UAT"

foreach ($definitionid in $definitionids)
{
    $definitionid
    $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/definitions/${definitionId}?api-version=7.0"

    $Def = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token" } -Method GET -ContentType application/json

    foreach ($environment in $Def.environments)
    {
        $environmentName = $environment.name


        if ( $environmentName -eq $targetEnv )
        {
            Write-Host "INFO: Environment Name is $environmentName"
            Write-Host "INFO: artifactConditions are:"
            $artifactConditions = $environment.conditions
            $artifactConditions | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
            Write-Host "========================================New condition========================================"
            $newCondition = @{
                "conditionType" = "artifact"
                "name" = "_PublishPipelineArtifacts-CI"
                "value" = @"
{"sourceBranch":"$branchName","tags":[],"useBuildDefinitionBranch":false,"createReleaseOnBuildTagging":false}
"@
            }
            $newCondition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
            Write-Host "========================================Environemnt UAT conditions========================================"
            $environment.conditions += $newCondition
            $environment.conditions | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
            Write-Host "========================================Update release pipeline definition ========================================"
            $updateDef_body = ConvertTo-Json($Def) -Depth 100 # | Out-File "C:\Users\Alvin.AZ\Desktop\newDef.json"
            $updateDef_body

            Write-Host "INFO: adding release branch to release '$branchName' to release pipeline"
            $updateDef_uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=7.0"
            $updateDef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateDef_uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token" } -Method PUT -Body $updateDef_body -ContentType application/json
            $updateDef

        }
    }
}



Perfect. It's working flawlessly!
